# R lmer formula is correct? Please help me

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I would like to make a statistical analysis in R using `lmer()`.
I analyzed 6 speaker voice during 18 months. The months divided into 4 periods: quarters 1, 2, 3, and 4.

My data:

dependent variable: X continuous
fixed factor: quarters
random factor: speakers

my formula is:

```
m <- lmer(X ~ quarters + (1 | speaker), data = v)
```

**the output is**:

```
Formula: X ~ quarters + (1 | speaker)
   Data: v

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4219.4   4253.0  -2103.7   4207.4     1966 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.60919 -0.72724 -0.05942  0.65965  2.70657 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 speaker  (Intercept) 0.002817 0.05308 
 Residual             0.493093 0.70221 
Number of obs: 1972, groups:  speaker, 6

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    0.17173    0.05105   24.30000   3.364  0.00255
quartersQ2         -0.25136    0.05040 1972.00000  -4.988 6.64e-07
quartersQ4         -0.43192    0.05281 1951.40000  -8.179 4.44e-16
quartersQ5         -0.44146    0.05832 1869.50000  -7.569 5.86e-14
Correlation of Fixed Effects:
      (Intr) TQeQ2  TQeQ4 
quartersQ2 -0.748              
quartersQ4 -0.735  0.719       
quartersQ5 -0.673  0.654  0.630
```

My question: why don't I see the factor effect rather than the result for each group in the quarters?

What I am doing wrong?

---

Thank for the answering!
Sorry about it, I am not perfect in statistical analysis.
I would like to test that there is a differences among four quarters.

My first question is that this analysis is correct? How can it interpreted?
And I have show in the example analysis (sleepstudy), that in the output the "Fixed Effects" it can be seen the fixed facor names, not the groups names of the fixed factor.
What is a difference? Why in the output can be seen the groups name (excluded the first quarter Q1).

It is not worng that there is a high Correlation of Fixed Effects?

Sorry about my bad knowledge:(

Thank

Comment: Are you trying to include a random intercept for "speaker" and that's the effect you are looking for? What "factor effect" are you talking about? Really this seems more like a question about interpreting a statistical model rather than programming this question better belongs at [stats.se]

Comment: If you want ANOVA-like statistics from your model, `car::Anova()` does exactly that. This would give you an ANOVA table with statistics for the "quarters" factor.

Comment: or `afex::mixed()`.

Comment: Are your quarters really Q1, Q2, Q4 and Q5?

Comment: Could you help how could make it a correct way, if I would like to test the quarters effect (my quarter level: Q1,Q2,Q4,Q5) on my data X?